# Matching one of several nodes with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm scraping a series of pages that alternate between using `<b>` and `<strong>` for the data I want to scrape. Is there a way I can use `html_nodes()` to get both `<b>` and `<strong>` nodes? I tried listing both node types using `c()` but that throws an error.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"http://washingtonpost.com/weather/2019/01/01/dc-area-forecast-breezy-today-with-increased-sunshine-more-rain-come-this-week/" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(c("b", "strong"))
```

Comment: Try `html_nodes("b, strong")`

Comment: what data on the webpage are you after if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @nate.edwinton I'm a huge fan of the Capital Weather Gang. I'm interested in analyzing the Daily Digit. How predictable is it? Does it act more like a time series or independent observations?